# How to change alpha of children

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, alpha

in Unity I have a game object as parent and two child text-objects as children. Also there is an image child-object (three children altogether).

Now I want to change the alpha of the game-object's three children. How do I accomplish this programmatically?

I have this code but it doesn't work with text and image-objects:

```
public void setAlpha(float alpha) {
SpriteRenderer[] children = GetComponentsInChildren<SpriteRenderer>();
Color newColor;
foreach(SpriteRenderer child in children) {
    newColor = child.color;
    newColor.a = alpha;
    child.color = newColor;
    }
}
```

Comment: As Text and Image, are you referring to UI elements?
If so, you must GetComponentsInChildren<Text> and GetComponentsInChildren<Image>.
Don't forget to include UnityEngine.UI

Comment: Yes, I am referring to UI elements. I want to change the alpha of the parent's children. How do I make this in Unity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code would work if you were working with a `SpriteRenderer`.

You can accomplish that by changing the alpha channel of the color property of the `Text` and `Image`, very similar from what you did:

```
public void setAlpha(float alpha) {
    Color newColor;

    Image[] childrenImg = GetComponentsInChildren<Image>();
    foreach(Image img in childrenImg) {
        newColor = img.color;
        newColor.a = alpha;
        img.color = newColor;
    }

    Text[] childrenText = GetComponentsInChildren<Text>();
    foreach(Text text in childrenText) {
        newColor = text.color;
        newColor.a = alpha;
        text.color = newColor;
    }
}
```

Don't forget to include `using UnityEngine.UI;` on top of your script, as `Text` and `Image` are UI elements.

Comment: Beat me to it by a second

Comment: I'll check this out ASAP. Thank you so much!:)

Answer (score 3):

There is no need to reinvent the wheel. 
For *UI elements* there is a ready-made component **[CanvasGroup](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ugui@1.0/manual/class-CanvasGroup.html)**:

[image]

It has the **Alpha** property which is applied to all the children.